# Drupal 9 Configuration Synchronization Error

Tags: drupal, configuration, drupal-views, drupal-9

I am trying to import views from one of my Drupal 9 sites, we will call it Drupal A to another Drupal 9 site, we will call it Drupal B.

I keep getting this error:

"Error message

The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons:

Configuration project.settings depends on the project extension that will not be installed after import."

I can not seem to track down where that project.settings is enabled but I did make a complete copy of the Drupal 9 A site and try to change just a field or two in a view, and import it into the original Drupal 9 site and I still get that error. Because of this finding, it leads me to think that project.settings is actually installed on both sites, but there is some other bug related to it.

Any ideas, suggestions, clarifying questions are welcomed! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed the project module but you left the `project setting config yml` file as is. This time to time happens if we **forget** to add *all related configs* into the repo.

Either you can **delete** project.settings configuration in your **config sync** folder or you can **install** the **project module** and continue to use it.

Regards,